# What is the difference between Keras' MaxPooling1D and GlobalMaxPooling1D functions?

Tags: keras, max-pooling

Both MaxPooling1D and GlobalMaxPooling1D are described as a max pooling operation for temporal data.

`keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=None, padding='valid')`

I understand that GlobalMaxPooling1D takes no input parameters. 
`keras.layers.pooling.GlobalMaxPooling1D()`

I would just like to visually understand how the two of them differ in the way they work?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**Td;lr** `GlobalMaxPooling1D` for temporal data takes the max vector over the
steps dimension. So a tensor with shape [10, 4, 10] becomes a tensor with shape [10, 10] after global pooling. `MaxPooling1D` takes the max over the steps too but constrained to a pool_size for each stride. So a [10, 4, 10] tensor with `pooling_size=2` and `stride=1` is a [10, 3, 10] tensor after `MaxPooling(pooling_size=2, stride=1)`

**Long answer with graphic aid**

Lets say we have a simple sentence with 4 words and we have some vector encoding for the words (like [word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) embeddings). Of course you wont normally max pool over an embedding Tensor but this should do for an example. Also global pooling works across channels but I'll leave that out of this illustration. Finally, things get slightly more complicated with padding but we dont need that here either.

Suppose we have `MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1).` Then

```
the  [[.7, -0.2, .1]   | pool size is two                  
boy   [.8, -.3,  .2]   | so look at two words at a time    | stride=1 will
will  [.2, -.1,  .4]     and take the max over those       | move the pool down
live  [.4  -.4,  .8]]    2 vectors. Here we looking         1 word. Now we look  
                            'the' and 'boy'.                'boy' and 'will' and 
                                                            take the max.
```

So that will result in a [1, 3, 3] Tensor with the each timestep being the max over a 2D pool. And since we had 3 pools we have effectively downsampled our timesteps from 4 to 3.

However, if we use `GlobalMaxPooling1D` we will just take the max vector of that sentence (Tensor) which is probably the vector representation of the word 'live'.

Indeed, here is how GlobalMaxPooling1D is defined in keras

```
class GlobalMaxPooling1D(_GlobalPooling1D):
    """Global max pooling operation for temporal data.
    # Input shape
        3D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, steps, features)`.
    # Output shape
        2D tensor with shape:
        `(batch_size, features)`
    """

    def call(self, inputs):
        return K.max(inputs, axis=1)
```

Hopefully that helps, please ask for me to clarify anything.

Additionally here is a example that you can play with:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, GlobalMaxPooling1D, MaxPooling1D

D = np.random.rand(10, 6, 10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape=(6, 10), return_sequences=True))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')

# print the summary to see how the dimension change after the layers are 
# applied

print(model.summary())

# try a model with GlobalMaxPooling1D now

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape=(6, 10), return_sequences=True))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')

print(model.summary())
```

Comment: That's a great explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is a [x, y, z] Tensor ? I'm new to tensors. I understand it is a 3 dimensional linear relation object. And what are pools ? Is it the number of words it reads in this case ? Don't hesitate to redirect me to a link or a tutorial if it is too long to explain

Comment: how does K.max() work on two vectors? by comparing the norm?

Answer (score 1):

@ThePassenger [x, y, z] can be seen as that you have an "array" with x elements where each element is a matrix with y rows and z columns. but also as you have a matrix aith x rows and y columns and for every element you have an array of z elements.

pools are just a way to diminish a tensor for example, if you have a matrix of x rows and y columns applying pooling can give you a matrix of x-n rows and the same y-m columns.